# GitHub API rate limit exceeded

Tags: jenkins, github, github-api, rate-limiting

In my jenkins job, I'm getting this error for my bot user.
The limit is 5000 for me and I see that every second about 100 requests are going and I'm not sure which job/service is using up the bot's requests. Ideally my other jenkins jobs should take up maximum 1 request per minute.

Is there any way to find out what is causing such a high request rate? Or any API call to list all the API calls made within the last minute or something similar?

Answer (score 3):

Browse https://JENKINS_URL/log/ and add a logger on `org.kohsuke.github.GitHub`.
Depending on the plugins you use, you may want to log other packages, for instance `org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source`

Also give a look at the Jenkins JIRA, there are many related tickets and various fixes or improvements available. For instance [JENKINS-36121](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36121) can be a good starting point.